# Should you capture data members by reference or with [this] in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

If I need to generate a lambda that calls a member function. Should I capture by reference or capture `this`? My understanding is that `&` captures only the members used, but `this` captures all data members. Is it better to use `&`?

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    int mFunc() {
      // accesses member variables
    }

    std::function<int()> get() {
      //return [this] () { return this->mFunc(); };
      //  or
      //return [&] () { return this->mFunc(); };
    }

  private:
    // member variables
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the specific example you've provided, capturing by `this` is what you want. Conceptually, capturing `this` by reference doesn't make a whole lot of sense, since you can't change the value of `this`, you can only use it as a pointer to access members of the class or to get the address of the class instance. Inside your lambda function, if you access things which implicitly use the `this` pointer (e.g. you call a member function or access a member variable without explicitly using `this`), the compiler treats it as though you had used `this` anyway. You can list multiple captures too, so if you want to capture both members and local variables, you can choose independently whether to capture them by reference or by value. The following article should give you a good grounding in lambdas and captures:

https://crascit.com/2015/03/01/lambdas-for-lunch/

Also, your example uses `std::function` as the return type through which the lambda is passed back to the caller. Be aware that `std::function` isn't always as cheap as you may think, so if you are able to use a lambda directly rather than having to wrap it in a `std::function`, it will likely be more efficient. The following article, while not directly related to your original question, may still give you some useful material relating to lambdas and `std::function` (see the section *An alternative way to store the function object*, but the article in general may be of interest):

https://crascit.com/2015/06/03/on-leaving-scope-part-2/

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is a good explanation of what `&`, `this` and the others indicate when used in the capture list.

In your case, assuming that all what you have to do is calling a member function of the instance that is actually referenced by the `this` of the method that is currently executing, put `this` in your capture list should be enough.

Comment: cppreference is nice if you have a rough a idea of how something works and want to look it up. I disagree heavily that is has a "good" explanation for the question of the OP. At least not in the sense of "good" being "understandable for a beginner".

Answer (score 7):

Capturing `this` and capturing by reference are two orthogonal concepts. You can use one, both, or none. It doesn't make sense to capture `this` by reference but you can capture other variables by reference while capturing `this` by value.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a clear-cut situation where on is better than the other. Rather, the two (at least potentially) accomplish slightly different things. For example, consider code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

    class foo { 
        int bar = 0;
    public:
        void baz() {
            int bar = 1;
            auto thing1 = [&] { bar = 2; };
            auto thing2 = [this] { this->bar = 3; };

            std::cout << "Before thing1: local bar: " << bar << ", this->bar: " << this->bar << "\n";    
            thing1();
            std::cout << "After thing1: local bar: " << bar << ", this->bar: " << this->bar << "\n";
            thing2();
            std::cout << "After thing2: local bar: " << bar << ", this->bar: " << this->bar << "\n";
        }
    };


int main() { 
    foo f;
    f.baz();
}
```

As you can see, capturing `this` captures *only* the variables that can be referred to via `this`. In this case, we have a local variable that shadows an instance variable (yes, that's often a bad idea, but in this case we're using it to show part of what each does). As we see when we run the program, we get different results from capturing `this` vs. an implicit capture by reference:

```
Before thing1: local bar: 1, this->bar: 0
After thing1: local bar: 2, this->bar: 0
After thing2: local bar: 2, this->bar: 3
```

As to the specifics of capturing everything vs. only what you use: neither will capture any variable you don't use. But, since `this` is a pointer, capturing that one variable gives you access to everything it points at. That's not unique to `this` though. Capturing any pointer will give you access to whatever it points at.

Comment: Barring your local `int bar = 1` declaration, capturing `[&]` and capturing `[this]` would be entirely equivalent, correct? (they would both capture `foo::bar` by reference) .. or even capturing `[=]` for that matter