# Lambda capturing - what is the difference between & and this?

Tags: c++, lambda

Could you please tell me the difference between capturing of `[this]` and `[&]`? (In case of a lambda is defined inside a member function of the class)

As I understood, there is no difference between both of them.

1. `[this]` - `[this]` means capturing all the member data of the class. Capturing `[this]` means capturing the address of the object.

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   class Foo {
       int x;
   public:
       Foo() : x(10) {}

       void bar() {
           // Increment x every time we are called
           auto lam = [this](){ return ++x; };
           std::cout << lam() << std::endl;
       }
   };

   int main() {
       Foo foo;
       foo.bar(); // Outputs 11
       foo.bar(); // Outputs 12
   }
   ```
2. `[&]` - `[&]` means capture all variables by reference all variables mean local variable, global variable and member data of the class.

   ```cpp
   class Foo {
       int x;
   public:
       Foo() : x(10) {}

       void bar() {
           // Increment x every time we are called
           auto lam = [&](){ return ++x; };
           std::cout << lam() << std::endl;
       }
   };

   int main() {
       Foo foo;
       foo.bar(); // Outputs 11
       foo.bar(); // Outputs 12
   }
   ```

I believe that there is no difference between `[this]` and `[&]`. Because by both capturing data is captured by reference. so the data can be changed.

- `[this]` captures address of the data (reference value)
- `[&]` captures all data by reference

Is my understanding is wrong? Please give me some advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ lambda capture this vs capture by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575563/c-lambda-capture-this-vs-capture-by-reference)

Comment: `[&]` itself doesn't capture data members at all. But when you write `[&]`, `this` is captured implicitly: `[&]` is equivalent to `[&, this]`.

Comment: @Evg  Thanks. then basically if i use member data of the class in lambda expression, can I use [&] or [&, this] or [this] for the same purpose? Thanks. I will choose one of them for coding.

Comment: Yes, you can use any one of them. But if you only access data members inside a lambda, `[this]` is all you need. So I suggest using `[this]` to be explicit about your intention.

Comment: @Evg Thank you for the kind explanation. thanks.

Comment: For clarification: `[=]` won't capture data members by value. It will capture `this` implicitly (before C++20), *effectively* capturing data members by reference.